# load many images

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

I'm trying to load many picture from internet in many imageView with progressBar.I succeed to do it but the problem all the images are loaded in the first imageView (as slider).but I don't know to to make it correct I mean to download each picture in one imageView:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter to your `DownloaderAsyncTask`s constructor. Use it at `onPostExecute`

```
int mIndex;
public DownloaderAsyncTask(Context context, int index) {
    mContext = context;
    mIndex = index;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    Intent intA = new Intent("...");
    intA.putExtra("resultCounter", mIndex );
    intA.putExtra("int", progress[0]);
    context.sendBroadcast(intA);
}

protected void onPostExecute(ByteArrayBuffer result) {
    Intent intB = new Intent("....");
    intB.putExtra("resultCounter", mIndex );
    intB.putExtra("image", result.toByteArray());
    context.sendBroadcast(intB);
}
```

Change initialization of asynctasks with your new constructor.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    DownloaderAsyncTask asyncTask = new DownloaderAsyncTask(getApplicationContext(), i);
    asyncTask.execute(links[i]);
}
```

Also change the to resultCounter tag when you get progCounter value

```
// Broadcast receiver for PROGRESS BAR
BroadcastReceiver receiveProgress = new BroadcastReceiver(){
public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, Intent intent) {
   int progress    = intent.getIntExtra("int", 0);
   int progCounter = intent.getIntExtra("resultCounter", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a project like this. I used this [lazy loader](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) and got success.

Answer (score 0):

This is your mistake

In your **BroadcastReceiver receiveImage**

You are trying to get the value of **progCounter** from the intent.

```
  int progCounter = intent.getIntExtra("resultCounter", 0);
```

But in your Async Task you are not sending any intent of **resultCounter** so each time you trying to get the value of intent it will give you **0 ("resultCounter", 0)** as no intent is there.

Comment: sorry Actually I delete it bc it sends evrytime 0, I think bc when I make new call from the service it resend resultCounter 0, I wanted to increment this value but I couldn't.  protected void onPostExecute(ByteArrayBuffer result) {
        Intent intB = new Intent("...");
        intB.putExtra("image", result.toByteArray());
        intB.putExtra("resultCounter", id);
        context.sendBroadcast(intB);
        id++;
    }